# Enforce tags and it's value Azure Policy using Terraform

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to enforce user to add a tag and it's value, in my example "Environment" for the name and "Production" for the value. But here I have a problem with my code, an error that I cannot resolve that's why i'm here. The error concerns the parameter "tagValue" and he doesn't seem to be recognized by the existing policy, here "azurerm_policy_definition". Thank you in advance for your help.

```
variable "requiredTag" {
  default = "environment"
}

variable "requiredValue" {
  default = "production"
}

resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "requiredTag" {
  name                 = "Deny-RequiredTag-${var.requiredTag}"
  display_name         = "Tag obligatoire '${var.requiredTag}'"
  description          = "Affectation de la stratégie de balise requise pour '${var.requiredTag}'"
  policy_definition_id = "${azurerm_policy_definition.requiredTag.id}"
  scope                = "/subscriptions/0000000000/resourceGroups/PolicyLab"
  parameters           = <<PARAMETERS
  {
    "tagValue": {
        "value": "${var.requiredValue}"
    },
    "tagName": {
        "value": "${var.requiredTag}"
    }
}
PARAMETERS
}

resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "requiredTag" {
  name         = "Deny-RequiredTag-Resource"
  display_name = "Deny a Required Tag on a Resource"
  description  = "Deny all resources for a required tag"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "All"
  policy_rule  = <<POLICY_RULE
  {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
        "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
      }
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
    }
}
POLICY_RULE

  parameters   = <<PARAMETERS
  {
    "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Name",
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
        }
    },
    "tagValue": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Value",
            "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
        }
    }
}
PARAMETERS

}
```

And here this is the error :

```
    Error: policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidPolicyParameterUpdate" Message="The policy contains new parameter(s) 'tagValue' which are not present in the existing policy and have no default value. New parameters may be added to a policy only if they have a default value."

  on main.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "requiredTag":
  34: resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "requiredTag" {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The policy contains new parameter(s) 'tagValue' which are not present in the existing policy and have no default value. 
>   New parameters may be added to a policy only if they have a default value.

Either delete the existing policy, or add a default value to you terraform script.

```
    "tagValue": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Value",
            "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
        },
        "defaultValue": [ "production" ]
    }
```

Comment: thanks! it works know, I added a default value, if  I had another problem can I pm you ?

Comment: Just open another question, there are more people who  are happy to help. 
And if my answer solved your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark so we keep the platform nice and clean :-)